# Inconsistent mongo results with unique field

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Not sure when this issue cropped up but I am not able to fetch items from mongo consistently. I have 4000+ items in the db. Here's the schema.

```
var Order = new Schema({
 code: {
  type: String,
  unique: true
},
...
});
```

Now run some queries:

```
Order.find().exec(function(err, orders) {
 console.log(orders.length); // always 101 
})

Order.find().limit(100000).exec(function(err, orders) {
 console.log(orders.length); // varies, sometimes 1150, 1790, 2046 - never more
})
```

Now if I remove the 'unique: true' from schema it will always return the total amount:

```
Order.find().exec(function(err, orders) {
 console.log(orders.length); // always 4213 (correct total)
})
```

Any idea as to why this behavior occurs? afaik the codes are all unique (orders from a merchant). This is tested on 3.8.6, 3.8.8

Comment: What do you get when, on your MongoDB shell, you type the following command: `db.orders.distinct('code').length`?

Comment: I get 4199 - which seems right - I have had a few duplicate orders come in - which incidentally was why I added unique but doesn't seem  to always stop duplicate ones

Comment: Hmm. And can you check if the `err` parameter is coming up null, or is mongoose reporting an error. So, in your callbacks, if you add `if (err) console.log(err);` do you get anything?

Comment: Here's my guess - there are duplicate items in there and Mongo is freaking out and choking in a sync way - it never gets higher than 2046 whichI bet is a duplicate - a few times it will stop early so I think it a) stops on duplicate and b) it does so sync or not in same "process" as fetching and will sometimes stop earlier. I bet if I remove the dups it will prob work though I wish there was some errors

Comment: Yup: https://github.com/learnboost/mongoose/issues/1225

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok issue was indeed unique index being not there/corrupted. I a guilty of adding the unique index later on in the game and probably had some dups already which prevented Mongo from creating indexes.

I removed the duplicates and then in the mongo shell did this:

```
db.orders({name: 1}, {unique: true, dropDubs: true});
```

I would think the above would remove dups but it would just die because of the dups. I am sure there is a shell way to do this but I just did it with some js code then ran the above to recreate the index which can be verified with:

```
db.orders.getIndexes()
```

Comment: Might just be typos in your post, but it should be `db.orders.ensureIndex` not `db.orders`, and it's `dropDups`, not `dropDubs`.

Comment: Lol that's prob an issue :) I was wondering about that but copied it from some other SO answer - thanks