# Mongoose returning inconsistent results

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm experiencing a strange problem in Mongoose related to `find` queries.  When I run the query below, I get a variable number of results.  I will get a consistent 210 results when querying in Mongo, but usually get between 198-210 results when doing the same thing through Mongoose.  I've tried the query with and without indexes set.

Any suggestions on what might be causing this would be greatly appreciated.

**Customer Model:**

```
subscriptions: [
  {
    renewal: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: false
    }
  }
]
```

**Query**

```
Customer.find({ "subscriptions.renewal": true }, {}, { timeout: false })
```

Comment: `renewal:
    type: Boolean
    default: false` is not proper JavaScript as far as I know. you seem to be mussing `{}`

Comment: You are correct, I forgot to convert the example from coffeescript.  I'll fix that.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23283308/inconsistent-mongo-results-with-unique-field

Comment: Thanks leroydev.  That issue is a bit different, but after reading it I tried deleting my indexes and that seems to have fixed the problem.  I'll post that as the solution once I'm sure I know all of the details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem ultimately cleared up when I removed the Customer collection indexes from Mongo (not just the definitions in the schema).  Anyone experiencing this issue might want to give that a try.